# Calculate an arithmetic expression over a variable without knowing its type

Tags: java

I have an arithmetic expression that uses (* / + -) operators. There are three types of variables - Integer, Float or Double. The type of the variable will be selected by writing in the command line the words "double", "float" or "integer". I already wrote the program, but I do not like my code...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Work {

    InitializeForType init;
    String calculate_for;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    void  go() {
        try {
            calculate_for = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (calculate_for.equals("double")){init = new InitializeForType<Double>();init.setA(1.23);}
            if (calculate_for.equals("float")){init = new InitializeForType<Float>();init.setA(1.23f);}
            if (calculate_for.equals("integer")){init = new InitializeForType<Integer>();init.setA(1);}
        } catch (java.io.IOException io) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
        System.out.println(calculate(init.A));
    }


    private String calculate(Object a) {

        boolean is_double = a instanceof Double;
        boolean is_float = a instanceof Float;

        return "(arctg(2*c)/d + 2)/(d + a - 1) " +  " = (arctg(" + 2 *
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) + ")/" + a + " + 2)/(" + a + " + " + a + " - 1)" + " = (" + Math.atan(2 *
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a)))) + "/" + a + " + 2)/(" + a + " + " + a + " - 1)" + " = (" + (Math.atan(2 *
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a)))) /
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) + 2) + ")/(" + (
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) +
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) - 1.0) + ")" + " = " + (Math.atan(2 *
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a)))) /
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) + 2) / (
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) +
            (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) - 1.0);
    }

    private Double toDouble(Object ob) {
        return Double.parseDouble(ob.toString());
    }

    private Float toFloat(Object ob) {
        return Float.parseFloat(ob.toString());
    }

    private Integer toInt(Object ob) {
        return Integer.parseInt(ob.toString());
    }

    private static class InitializeForType<someType> {
        someType A;
        void setA(someType a) {
            this.A = a;
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want the arithmetic part of the code to be repeated three times. And I wrote like `(is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a)))`.... I know that it is very stupid, but it works.

Comment: Is this not more suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The whole `is_double` business is unnecessary. You can concat `a` without knowing its type. And why would you take what you know is already a `Double` and parse its `toString()` again? Ever heard of casting?

Comment: Also, all number types extend `Number`. You can call `((Number)a).doubleValue()` since your ternary expression promotes to double anyway.

Comment: Even if you did want the ternary expression for some reason, there's no need to keep repeating it. Just store it in a variable.

Comment: @Artemis The asker worded it that way, but at its core this is a question asking how to do something in a given language. The asker could have done without their actual code, as it is irrelevant, and asked with a simpler generic example. Despite having a working program, asker does not have a working example of what specifically is being asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an object-oriented solution if you want your code to be more DRY.
Then use polymorphism to handle each special case.

What you have done is use flags and procedural programming. It's not terrible; it's just not easily readable or flexible. What if you needed to add String values to this program? Well, you are going to have to modify everything, now.

Hopefully, that gives you some pointers without having to rewrite the entire program from you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use String.valueOf(a) instead of .. (is_double ? toDouble(a) : (is_float ? toFloat(a) : toInt(a))) ?

[See some samples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm)

Comment: It is school task, and as I understand the calculation should be of a certain type (Integer, Float, Double) to understand OOP.

Comment: Then you could write three methods that take as argument a Double/Float or Integer. String  m(Double d) {}, String  m(Float f){...}, String m(Integer i){..}

Comment: Then the arithmetic calculation code is repeated three times in three methods. I tried to make a separate method for an arithmetic expression... earlier I declared the variable as an object and through a parameterized class. I tried as you say, I created three methods but I got error like this: calculate java.lang.Double cannot be applied to java.lang.Object... –